# Optimizing emberjs filter search

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a simple search input that filters through an api response that is represented in a html table. Filtering works very well but for some reasons I feel like it was a very ugly way to go by it. So I', wondering what would be a better way to go about it.

here is my controller:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    searchKeyword: null,

    searchResults: function(){
        var searchText = this.get('searchText');

        if( ! searchText) return;

        //YOUVE ALREADY GOT THE COMPANIES DONT GO BACK TO THE SERVICE
        var companies =  this.get('model');

        var regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');

        return companies.filter(function(company){
            return company.name.match(regex);
        });
    }.property('searchText', 'model')
});
```

here is my route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    model: function(){
        var adapter = AddressBookHomeAdapter.create();
        var companies =  adapter.findAll();
        return companies;
    }
});
```

here is my adapter (I'm not using Ember-Data):

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
    findAll: function(){
        return ajax('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/companies')
            .then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            });
    }
});
```

here is the very ugly (in my opinion) html `{{#each}}`:

```
    {{#if searchResults}}
        {{#each searchResult in searchResults}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{searchResult.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        {{#each m in model}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{m.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
```

Is there a way for me to directly filter the model route? So I don't need the necessary if statement? Also I should probably make this a component correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change your controller so you always return all records when no search term is entered, and only `filter` when `searchKeyword` has text. Then in your template you can remove the `if` statement and the 2nd `each`. 
Something *similar* to the following:

js:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    searchKeyword: null,

    searchResults: function() {

        var searchKeyword = this.get('searchKeyword'),
            companies     = this.get('model');

        if (Ember.isEmpty(searchKeyword)) return companies;

        var regex = new RegExp(searchKeyword, 'i');

        return companies.filter(function(company){
            return company.name.match(regex);
        });

    }.property('searchKeyword', 'model')
});
```

hbs:

```
{{#each searchResult in searchResults}}
<tr>
    <td>{{searchResult.name}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks and should I make this a component?

Comment: I can't say you *should or shouldn't*, but it's generally a good practice, especially you think you'll be reusing it in more than one place.